# Data coverts to some other form while sending an API request in my Flutter App

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am trying to send an API request in my flutter App for filtering the items in my app. I want the data to be filtered between certain 2 numbers.

This is what I want.

```
http://3.237.223.130/careWorker/get-parttime-jobList?workingHoursFrom=02.30&workingHoursTo=03.00
```

but the API call going from the app looks like this

```
http://3.237.223.130/careWorker/get-parttime-jobList?workingHoursFrom=02%3A30&workingHoursTo=03%3A00
```

The '.' is being converted into '%3A'

How can I send the API request in the form I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them is the same value.

Seems like the query parameters are being `urlEncoded` while sending via API.

I have attached the image to show you the example.

[image]

You can test the URL encoded and decoded value [HERE](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/).

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the problem was something else. Anyways thank you so much for the help.